# Why does ggplot2's the eps font look different than the png?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently had to export using an `eps` filetype. I noticed that the fonts between the two figures were different i.e.,

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(hp, drat, 
      label = mpg, 
      data = mtcars) +
  geom_text(nudge_x = 15)


ggsave("test1.png", height = 6, width = 10, units = "in", dpi = 300)
```

png
[image: png-text]

and eps (a bolder font)

```
ggsave("test2.eps", device = "eps", height = 6, width = 10, units = "in", dpi = 300)
```

[image: eps-text]

Why does `ggplot2`'s eps font look different than the png?

Comment: Can you try to set the size for both images and see if this happens? E.g. `ggsave(height = 6, width = 10, units = "in", dpi = 300)`

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question in just a moment but this pattern still exists, but the sizes match

Comment: Can you try using `cairo_eps` as your device in the `ggsave()` code? E.g. `ggsave("test2.eps", device = cairo_eps, height = 6, width = 10, units = "in", dpi = 300)`

Comment: What package is `cairo_eps` from? I thought it was from `grDevices` but I am not seeing it there

Comment: Can I ask how you're uploading your eps file to SO?

Comment: I am pasting the output in the "upload image" of SO, is there another way I should consider? I also see the in using the preview app in osx

Comment: I think that's alright. This is a bit beyond me, but maybe `device = cairo_ps` will work for you? I don't know enough about the cairo system to give any better ideas. Could try `ggsave("test2.eps", device = cairo_ps, height = 6, width = 10, units = "in", dpi = 300)` (insert shoulder shrug)